Changing allowList to allow table, tr, td in popover
I want to display tables in my popovers.  I add table, tr, td to the allowList, but the popover still shows blank.
The popovers themselves work fine, but in the case of adding a table to them (like my example) it shows blank which leads me to believe how I am doing the allowList is wrong.
init all popovers with the new allowList options :
var myDefaultAllowList = bootstrap.Popover.Default.allowList;
//to allow elements and attributes on elements
//myDefaultAllowList.input = ['type', 'checked']; //extra allow example
myDefaultAllowList.table = [];
myDefaultAllowList.tr = [];
myDefaultAllowList.td = [];

let popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
let popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, { allowList: myDefaultAllowList, html: true });
});

example popup html :
<a data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="<table><tr><td>testing</td></tr></table>">popover example</a>


myDefaultAllowList.tbody = []; needs added to the allowList.  Even though I am not using it in my code, for whatever reason, it works when I add it to the allowList.  There must be some sort of 'check' on the bootstrap side of things for multiple allowed elements - i.e. if tbody isn't allowed then table, tr, td, etc. aren't allowed either.
